# Python3 Gui Suggestion for Timesheet Generation Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface

I'm still fairly new to Python and rusty to programming in general, so I decided to build a program to help me take care of my time sheets at work.  I work as a runner for an accounting firm, so as such, my time sheets can be filled with around 8 to 12 entries a day depending on how many deliveries I have to go and make.

My question is which GUI library would be most appropriate for a simple program like this?  Preferably I'd like one that has a nice tutorial with it so I can try to learn and understand exactly what I'm doing.  I'm using Python3 and would be running this on a Windows system.

Sorry if this is kind of a dumb question, but after all the Google searches I've done, most of the solutions offered were for libraries that were way more powerful than I would need.  This will be used by myself and at most, a small handful of my co-workers if they want to use it, so I'm not sure what licensing I would need to look out for to not have any legal issues.  I have no plans on making any money from this.

Comment: All library will be more powerful then you need.  Libraries need to handle multiple cases not just yours.  That being said, I'd probably look at tkinter, or a browser based solution.

Comment: True.  I guess I should have clarified by what I meant by "more powerful."  There were some libraries that contained things like touch controls and stuff like that, which just seemed way above and beyond what I needed.  I'll take a gander at tkinter, thanks!

Comment: Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I really and truly had searched and searched for information on my own.  But I'll know better in the future.

Comment: I would take a look at wxPython. Tutorial here: https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20Learn%20wxPython . Be warned, though, a timesheet program is a *lot* more work than you might at first think.